# C++ template alias and partial template class specializations

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

I am facing somehow unexpected results when using template aliases as arguments of template classes declaring partial specializations. In some cases, I even observe that GCC 8.2 and Clang 6.0.0 do not agree on the results. The code illustrating my cases can be found below.

```
// A template struct named Foo.
template<typename>
struct Foo {};

// A template alias for type Foo.
template<typename TYPE>
using AliasFoo = Foo<TYPE>;

// A variadic template alias for type Foo.
template<typename... ARGS>
using VariadicAliasFoo = Foo<ARGS...>;

// A template struct named Bar.
template<template<typename...> class TEMPLATE, typename TYPE>
struct Bar
{
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

// Partial specialization of template struct Bar.
template<template<typename...> class TEMPLATE, typename... ARGS>
struct Bar< TEMPLATE, TEMPLATE<ARGS...> >
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};


// The main function.
int main()
{
  // These compile time assertions are satisfied (as expected).
  static_assert(Bar<Foo, Foo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<Foo, AliasFoo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<Foo, VariadicAliasFoo<int> >::value, "");

  // These compile time assertions fails with Clang 6.0.0 but succeed with GCC 8.2
  static_assert(Bar<AliasFoo, Foo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<AliasFoo, AliasFoo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<AliasFoo, VariadicAliasFoo<int> >::value, "");

  // These compile time assertions fails with Clang 6.0.0 and GCC 8.2.
  static_assert(Bar<VariadicAliasFoo, Foo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<VariadicAliasFoo, AliasFoo<int> >::value, "");
  static_assert(Bar<VariadicAliasFoo, VariadicAliasFoo<int> >::value, "");

  // Always return zero.
  return 0;
}
```

My question is following, according to the standard (c++17) what should be the result of the last six compile time assertions in the above code?

Comment: Note that you don't need to provide a second argument to `static_assert` since C++17. Also, `return 0;` is superfluous. Moreover, you might consider inheriting `Bar` from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type`.

Comment: GCC implements [CWG 1286](https://wg21.link/cwg1286). Clang does not.